# Append tuple to a list for a given id

Tags: python, xml, list, for-loop, tuples

I have an xml file with several nodes, each one having different data. My goal is to create a list with tuples of values containing that information for each one but struggling to acomplish that.

```xml
<node id="950073331">
  <data key="d4">39.22685</data>
  <data key="d5">-4.58879</data>
  <data key="d6">950073331</data>
</node>
<node id="950073335">
  <data key="d4">39.22708</data>
  <data key="d5">-4.58489</data>
  <data key="d6">950073335</data>
</node>
```

This is the code I have but it prints a tuple of the same node for each data instead of adding all the data into the same one before switching to the next node.

```
nodes = []
for node in root.findall('n:graph/n:node',ns):
    id = node.get('id')
    for data in node:
        if (data.get('key')) != 'd6':
            coordinates = data.text
            nodes.append((id,coordinates))
print(nodes)
```

Output

```
nodes = [('950073331', '39.22685'), ('950073331', '4.58879'),
         ('950073335', '39.22708'), ('950073335', '4.58489') ... ]
```

The output I want:

```
nodes = [('950073331', '39.22685', '4.58879'),
         ('950073335', '39.22708', '4.58489') ... ]
```

PS: Sorry, quite a noob in python and xml `:/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a single `tuple` with all the data for each node. But you create one for each data point within a node. You could do for example:

```
nodes = []
for node in root.findall('n:graph/n:node',ns):
    data_lst = [node.get('id')]
    for data in node:
        if data.get('key') != 'd6':
            data_lst.append(data.text)
    nodes.append(tuple(data_lst))
print(nodes)
```

Or in Python3, you can do the shorter:

```
nodes = []
for node in root.findall('n:graph/n:node',ns):
    id = node.get('id')
    nodes.append((id, *(data.text for data in node if data.get('key') != 'd6')))
print(nodes)
```

Comment: knew was doing smthing dumb but won't notice it, mb. thank u very much for your help, working with python3 so going for the shortest approach :D now if for example i need to get the data values for a given node how will it be the fastest way of navigating to the tuple im searching for?